# Beginner Java Secret Number Guessing Program

Tags: java

This Java program is supposed to ask the user to input a maximum value, and then generate a random number between 1 and that maximum value. The user then guesses what the value is until they get it right. When the user is incorrect, the program tells them that they're too high or too low and increments the number of guesses. If the user is correct, the program displays the total number of guesses and asks the user if they would like to play again.

The issue I keep having is that sometimes, when I input a guess, the program skips over telling me I was too high, too low, or correct, and simply asks me if I would like to play again. I can't figure out why this is happening, and it seems to happen randomly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessNumber 
{


public static void main (String [] args)
{

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in); //create scanner object
    int maxNumber = 0; //declare variables
    int userGuess = 0;
    int totalGuesses = 0;
    int secretNumber = 0;
    String replay = "";

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Secret Number Generator!");

    do
    {
        System.out.println("Please input a maximum value for the secret number and press enter."); //prompt user to input a maximum value
        maxNumber = in.nextInt();

        secretNumber = (int) ((Math.random() * maxNumber) + 1); //generate the secret number

        System.out.println("A new secret number has been chosen!"
                + "\nWhat do you think it is? Input your guess and press enter."); //prompt user to input a guess
        userGuess = in.nextInt();

        while (userGuess < secretNumber) //while user's guess is less than the secret number
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, that is too low! Please try again."); //prompt user to input another guess; increment total number of guesses by 1
            userGuess = in.nextInt();
            totalGuesses ++;
        }

        while (userGuess > secretNumber) //while user's guess is greater than the secret number
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, that is too high! Please try again."); //prompt user to input another guess; increment total number of guesses by 1
            userGuess = in.nextInt();
            totalGuesses ++;
        }

        if (userGuess == secretNumber) //if user guesses correctly
        {
            System.out.println("Nice job! Your guess, " + secretNumber + " is correct!" //congratulate and display total number of guesses
                    + "\nTotal number of guesses: " + totalGuesses);
        }

        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Please input \"Yes\" or \"No\" and press enter."); //ask user if they would like to play again
        replay = in.next();

        while (!replay.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") && !replay.equalsIgnoreCase("No") //in case of invalid input
                && !replay.equalsIgnoreCase("\"Yes\"") && !replay.equalsIgnoreCase("\"No\""))
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, that is an invalid input. Please input \"Yes\" or \"No\" and press enter.");
            replay = in.next();
        }
    }   
    while(replay.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") || replay.equalsIgnoreCase("\"Yes\"")); //replay while user says yes

    if (replay.equalsIgnoreCase("No") || replay.equalsIgnoreCase("\"No\"")) //if user says no
    {
        System.out.print("Thanks for playing!");
    }

} //end of main method


} //end of class GuessNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have multiple while loops which doesn't make sense. if user enters bigger number then enter small one it will skip it.

you can shrink them all to one of them

```
while (userGuess != secretNumber){
   if(userGuess > secretNumber){
     //too high
   } else if(userGuess < secretNumber){
     //too low 
   } else{
     //nice got it
   }

}

//do you want to play again 
...
```

Comment: @msoliman I did upvote, but it doesn't show it since my reputation is so low. Not sure how else I would go about marking correct beyond that though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `while` loops for single evaluation conditions. Replace your three inner while loops with something like this (pseudocode):

```
int guess = readInteger()
while guess != number
    if guess < number print "too low"
    if guess > number print "too high"
assert guess == number
print "you guessed correctly; good job!"
```

And then run that through the game loop that keeps the game going.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having some looping troubles, and like the others suggest please avoid so many unnecessary nested loops when a simple selection structure like "if else" or "select case" will work. Should save you some fuss that way too.

To make your app run more predictably I would suggest throwing the "game" logic into a method. Here is an example that runs. Hope it helps you out some!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String replay = "";

    do {
    runGame(); //run method to guess number
    System.out.println("Play again? Enter Yes or No");
    replay = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    }
    while(!replay.equals("no"));
}

private static void runGame() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //create scanner object
    int maxNumber = 0; //declare variables
    int userGuess = 0;
    int totalGuesses = 0;
    int secretNumber = 0;


    System.out.println("Welcome to the Secret Number Generator!");
    System.out.println("Please input a maximum value for the secret number and press enter."); //prompt user to input a maximum value
    maxNumber = in.nextInt();

    secretNumber = (int) ((Math.random() * maxNumber) + 1); //generate the secret number

    System.out.println("A new secret number has been chosen!" + "\nWhat do you think it is? Input your guess and press enter."); //prompt user to input a guess
    userGuess = in.nextInt();

    while (userGuess != secretNumber) {
        if (userGuess < secretNumber) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, that is too low! Please try again."); //prompt user to input another guess; increment total number of guesses by 1
        } else if (userGuess > secretNumber) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, that is too High! Please try again."); //prompt user to input another guess; increment total number of guesses by 1
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, but that's not right. Try again...");
        }

        totalGuesses++;
        userGuess = in.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("You guessed it! After " + totalGuesses + "   tries.");
    }
}
```